# Is there a SAML Identity Provider Framework for Spring Security 6?

Tags: spring, spring-security, migration

I have a server that acts as a SAML 2.0 Identity Provider using Spring Security 5 and the Spring Security SAML v2 library ([link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.extensions/spring-security-saml2-core/2.0.0.M31)). I have the need to upgrade Spring to version 6. The Spring SAML library has not been updated for version 6, but instead was merged into the core security project as stated [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-saml#overview). Looking at the Spring Security 6 API documentation ([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/index.html)) none of the Identity Provider packages under org.springframework.security.saml.provider.identity were ported over. Is there any Spring library for a SAML 2.0 Identity Provider that works with Spring 6?

I have tried looking through the Spring documentation as linked to above, including the Spring Security 6 migration guide ([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/saml2.html)), but have not found any documentation on the Identity Provider framework within Spring 6.

Comment: why not read the docs? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the additional link for me to review. However, there is no documentation there either about using SAML as the identity provider, nor any information on why this part of the framework was not transitioned to Spring 6 like the service provider portion. In lieu of finding valuable information in the docs, I was hoping that the knowledge base here would have some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an issue thread under the Spring Security project on GitHub explaining that SAML 2.0 IdP is not supported under any current Spring project because of a lack of demand.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10231